# WiFi gets disconnected and system gets stuck

Tags: networking, 18.04

The WiFi connection gets disconnected frequently in my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.
After that the WiFi settings gets stuck and the only way to fix this is to manually reboot by long pressing the power button because the restart button does not work. [image]

Output of `'lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list'`

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 32)
    Subsystem: Dell QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1028:0310]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
03:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: SK hynix Device [1c5c:1527]
0: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: I have already restarted my system. Will the output make sense now?

Comment: Why do you have 2 root logins?

Comment: @heynnema i didn't login with even one. Whenever WiFi gets disconnected. This is what I see

Comment: You may wish to change your root password asap, and make sure your firewall is turned on.